# Efficient algorithms for multivariate piecewise (segmented) continuous linear regression

Tags: optimization, regression

### Questions

Hi,

I wonder if there is an efficient algorithm of multivariate piecewise linear regression.

I've seen [a post about the construction of multivariate piecewise linear approximator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997138/multivariate-piecewise-linear-interpolation), but the construction seems computationally inefficient.

Here, "efficient" means, for example, it is well-known that convex optimisation is "efficient".

### Thoughts

A multivariate piecewise linear approximator may be expressed as
$$
\hat{f}(x) = \max_{i=1, 2, \ldots N} a_i^T x + b_i.
$$
And if the regression problem is solved as the minimisation of "function distance", for example, $\min_{a_i, b_i} \lVert \hat{f} - f \rVert$, it seems not straightforward to be expressed as a known "easy" problem such as convex optimisation.
Anyone has a good idea?

Comment: Well the problem you pose is nonconvex, and there is no efficient exact method as far as I know. Hence, the question is if you are looking for convex heuristics/approximations, or implementable exact methods which still could be practically efficient although theoretically intractable.

Comment: and just to nit-pick. Convex optimization is not necessarily efficient. There are intractable convex problems.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks a lot!